# uploading files and set permissions

Tags: php, mysql

I have to upload files - for this I need to set permissions to 777 ... but the files can be accessed only the logged in users - what would be the best way to do this?

Thanks.

Comment: nothing yet ... I thought like making redirection with php ...but not sure if this is safe enough

Comment: 'logged in' = to your site or to the server? Be aware that 777 means someone could upload a hostile script and run it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming this is for a website, please try to avoid the use of 777 permissions, it will increase the likelihood of your website getting hacked.

You should instead investigate using another PHP Handler such as FastCGI or SUPHP, these will allow your website to run with the permissions of it's own FTP User rather than the Apache default, which will allow you to write to directories without having to relax permissions from the usual 755 for directories and 644 for files.

Worst case, even using the setfacl command to assign additional permissions for the apache/nobody/www-data user would be better than using chmod to open up your directory or directories to the entire world.

Comment: your answer seems to me like the best for me ... but I never used suPHP handlers and not sure if I know how to make them work.Thank you.

Comment: Do you have a control panel on your server? If you have Plesk it's a very simple matter to change the PHP Handler in the Web Hosting settings of the domain.

On WHM/cPanel servers the change can only be made on a global basis - install SuPHP/SuEXEC support from within WHM and you can then swap it over.

If you have a bare bones server, you'd need to investigate mod_fastcgi (assuming you're using Apache as your webserver) or even the php-fpm daemon as an alternative.

Answer (score 1):

You should check out the PHP function `chmod`.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.chmod.php

Answer (score 1):

Personally I don't think you'll need that heavy permissions. What I'd do is upload the files via PHP but save the file in a folder that's not accessible to the web, then when a guy wants to access his own file, instead of linking him to the file directly, you send him to a PHP script that streams the file down to him (after checking his credentials and ownership of the file, which you save in a DB or somewhere).